# Issue with composite unique key with MySQL

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I'm having a problem with a table of my MySQL database. It looks like this :

```
Images
------------
 id
 name
 page_name
 filename
```

I don't want two entries of this table to have the same "page_name" and "filename" (these fields are of the VARCHAR type). I did this :

```
alter table images add constraint page_image unique(page_name, filename);
```

This seems to work fine, but I'm often not allowed to add entries because of this constraint and I don't understand why. Here's what I currently have in this table :

```
 id  | name            | page_name | filename                               |
 187 | 59179246_XL.jpg |           | $1$sJY8OY2y$Sbl3TdqfuDmzuct4uq1Dr0.jpg |
 188 | 21287471_L.jpg  |           | $1$RYqR0EWw$zj9e2bccgx7yRoAfZTaL.jpg   |
 189 | 59179246_XL.jpg | Home page | $1$sJY8OY2y$Sbl3TdqfuDmzuct4uq1Dr0.jpg |
 190 | 59195969_L.jpg  |           | $1$Nl2k4xlG$b8M3BZqo8ndfRB04nk2J.jpg   |
 211 | 59195969_L.jpg  | Tarif     | $1$Nl2k4xlG$b8M3BZqo8ndfRB04nk2J.jpg   |
```

But the following query won't work :

```
insert into images(name, page_name, filename) select name, 'Tarif', filename from images where name like '59179246_XL%';
```

I get this error message :

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'Tarif-$1$sJY8OY2y$Sbl3TdqfuDmzuct4uq1Dr0.jpg' for key 'page_image'
```

Why am I getting this message?

Comment: Your goal is to add `Tarif` to `page_name` column. You went through all the records that match your `LIKE` query. Reason you're getting this error is because you already *have*  that entry (at least according to MySQL). If you want to insert into `images` while selecting from `images`, use `INSERT IGNORE` statement. It will happily ignore all errors that occur due to the constraint.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for your reply. I don't understand what you mean "you already have that entry". As far as I can see, there's no entry having these two values in common. Please explain.

Comment: @N.B. Also, what if I want this constraint to be active when this entry actually exist?

Comment: You can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement in that case. Constraint is active all the time, you just let the query execute with entries that are allowed to be inserted.

Comment: @N.B. Can you please explain the issue and why MySQL thinks that the entry already exist?

Comment: I don't see the entire data set, but MySQL apparently thinks it exists. Run the `select name, 'Tarif', filename from images where name like '59179246_XL%'` and inspect its output, compare to what you have.

Comment: @N.B. You have all the data set in my post. As expected, this query returns the lines of the 3rd entry (59179246_XL.jpg, Tarif, $1$sJY8OY2y$Sbl3TdqfuDmzuct4uq1Dr0.jpg)

Comment: @N.B. I also the results of the 1st one (59179246_XL.jpg, Tarif, $1$sJY8OY2y$Sbl3TdqfuDmzuct4uq1Dr0.jpg). PLease note that the first line has the same data, except the "page_name" that is empty.